# Snowflake - How to execute "desc integration" command using integration names coming from a variable?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting the following error upon executing the below script in Snowflake.

`SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 9 unexpected 'integration'. syntax error line 5 at position 21 unexpected ':'.`

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
$$
DECLARE
  si_name varchar ;
BEGIN
    si_name := 'ABC_DEF' ;
    desc integration :si_name ;
    return si_name ;
END ;
$$
;
```

If I remove the `desc integration` line then the script runs just fine displaying the variable value. But why isn't the same value getting passed inside the command?

Can anyone suggest how to resolve it?

I basically want to execute the `desc integration` command using integration names coming from a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `identifier` function in your script:

```
desc integration IDENTIFIER(:si_name);
```